# Displaying a resultset value in another column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum, case

AM NEW TO MYSQL... HELP ME TO SORT OUT THIS...

I have two result set like

### 1st result set

```
 NO,     TYPE,  FEE_AMT
'2156', 'FTP2', 100.00
'2156', 'FTP4', 200.00
'2156', 'FTP5', 100.00
'2156', 'FTP6', 100.00
'2156', 'FTP3', 100.00
```

### **2nd Resultset**

```
 NO,     TYPE,  FEE_AMT
'2156', 'FTP2', 100.00
'2156', 'FTP4', 200.00
'2156', 'FTP1', 100.00
'2156', 'FTP6', 100.00
'2156', 'FTP3', 100.00
```

I want to sum all FEE_AMT in one column as `feesum`.
I the result contains type=`'FTP5'` I want to display that corresponding fee_amt in next column as `abc_fee` else abc_amt=0;

**EXPECTED OUTPUT IS:**

**For 1st result set**

```
feesum abc_amt
600    100
```

**For 2nd result set**

```
feesum abc_amt
600    0
```

I know the formula for sum all but not the next column...
THANKS IN ADVANCE... :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(table1.FEE_AMT) AS feesum, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN table1.TYPE = 'FTP5' THEN table1.FEE_AMT ELSE 0 END) AS abc_amt
FROM table1
WHERE table1.NO = '2156';
```

Comment: @MonickaAkilan You have use SUM function because you want to sum of different records.